# RSA - Compute signature

Tags: rsa, signature

I have a question in (textbook) RSA. Suppose we have two public keys $pk_1=(e_1,N)$ and $pk_2=(e_2,N)$ (with $\gcd(e_1,e_2) = 1$). 
Assume that there are $\sigma$,$\sigma'$ such that $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ are a valid signature on $m_1$ and $m_2$ under $pk_1$ and $pk_2$ respectively ($m_1$ and $m_2$ are messages in $\mathbb{Z}_N$ ).
I am trying to compute the signature $\sigma$ from $N,e_1,e_2,m_1,m_2$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you implying $\sigma = Sig_{sk1}(m1)= Sig_{sk2}(m2)$? If so you only have to compute a classical signature either for $m1$ given $sk1$ or $m2$ given $sk2$. Note that signatures are computed with private keys, not public keys (in the case of RSA, use the exponent d and the prime factors $p,q$ of N)

Comment: Sorry for that, i mean $\sigma = Sig_{sk1}(m1)$ and  $\sigma'= Sig_{sk2}(m2)$

Comment: You are signing with public keys, are you aware this is not a proper way to peeform signatures?

Comment: I didn't mean that we sign with public keys. I mean that we sign with the private keys sk1,sk2 respectively, but these signatures are valid (under pk1,pk2).

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: No, I am trying to write a python program that checks the security of different schemes (and I want to cover scenarios of RSA too) . There is a similar open question in a cryptography book.

Comment: Welcome to crypto.SE. Sorry, but the question as worded makes no sense. For any valid RSA key $(e,N)$, any message in $\mathbb{Z}_N$ has a texbook RSA signature. Thus "Assume that there are.." is a tautology, and we are tempted to read it as "It is given..". But but then "trying to compute the signature $σ$" is regurgitating a given. Also, using $σ,σ'$ for the signatures of $m_1,m_2$ would be poor notation; and not coincidentally, there [originally](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/76826/1) was no $σ'$, and it is [gone again](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/170756).

Answer (score 0):

Let $d_1, d_2$ be inverses of $e_1,e_2$ respectively mod $(p-1)(q-1)$ where $N=pq$ with $p,q$ two large primes.

To sign the message $m_1$, you will compute $s_1={m_1}^{d_1}\ [N]$.

To verify the signature, provided $m_1, s_1$, one will compute ${s_1}^{e_1}\ [N]$ and check whether this equals to the message $m_1$ or not.

Comment: OK I see. Thank you for this. And if now we assume that there is σ such that σ is a valid signature on m1 and m2 under pk1 and pk2 respectively (m1 and m2 are messages in $Z_N$ ). Note : This time the signature is the same and i want to compute σ via N,e1,e2,m1,m2.

Comment: You do exactly the same. A signature is actually a pair $s, m$, where you provide the message $m$ that has been signed in $s$. Note that in practice, this is not likely to happen.